# VeeValidate fastExit with multple error not working

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I am using Veevalidate version 2. The documentation is either broken or not useful. I am trying to use multiple errors on the field but it only displays one. What am I missing? Here is my code:

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
    fastExit: false
});

Validator.extend("number", {
    getMessage: (field) =>
        "Error 1",
    validate: (value) => {
        if (/^[^-][0-9]+|[.][0-9]+/) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
});
Validator.extend("number2", {
    getMessage: (field) =>
        "The field is required",
    validate: (value) => {
        if (value == '') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    },
});

    <input
      class="ff"
      v-validate="'number|number2|required'"
      v-model="application.number"
    />
  </div>
  <span v-show="errors.has('number')" class="error">
    {{
    errors.first("number")
    }}
  </span>
  <span v-show="errors.has('number2')" class="error">
    {{
    errors.first("number2")
    }}
  </span>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an error for `number2`?

Comment: @AdamOrlov yes `Validator.extend("number2"`

Comment: @Nofel Which error is displayed?
Is it always `number` or `number2` or random?

Comment: Yes but you said there is only one error showing. And there is the `v-show` on `number2`. So my question is are you sure, the `number2` error should be displayed? Is there an `error` for `number2` in Veevalidates error bag?

Comment: @UtsavPatel it keep picking on old error message of `number` it is like it is ignoring `number2` and keeping old copy of `number` error message even after I comment it out

Comment: @AdamOrlov no it is not showing `number2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mclaren-5ylt1?file=/src/App.vue:0-429)

According to the docs you can display multiple errors with [`errors.collect`](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/displaying-errors.html#displaying-multiple-error-messages)

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="error in errors.collect('fieldName')">{{ error }}</li>
</ul>
```

In your example - the validation for `number1` is incorrect, you'd need something like `if (value.match(<regex>))`

#### main.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VeeValidate, { Validator } from "vee-validate";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
  fastExit: false
});

Validator.extend("shouldBeNumber", {
  getMessage: field => "Should be a number",
  validate: value => {
    if (value.match(/^[a-z]+/)) {
      return false;
    } else if (value.match(/^[0-9]+/)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
});

Validator.extend("shouldBeLongerThan3", {
  getMessage: field => "Field should be longer than 3 numbers",
  validate: value => {
    if (value.length < 3) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
});

Validator.extend("shouldNotIncludeSymbols", {
  getMessage: field => "Should not include symbols",
  validate: value => {
    if (value.match(/[^\w\s]+/)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

#### App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      class="ff"
      v-validate="'shouldBeNumber|shouldBeLongerThan3|shouldNotIncludeSymbols|required'"
      name="number"
      v-model="number"
    >
    <span v-bind:key="index" v-for="(error, index) in errors.collect('number')">{{ error }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      number: null
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The only problem I see here is that the error messageing are appending next to each other. whereas I want error to change depending on which condition is not met. right now the one is `Error 1The field is requiredThe number field is required`

Comment: since fastExit is false, this will show all validations that haven't passed - in the example you presented, `required` and `number2` are essentially the same

Comment: i'll change the example to be more realistic

Comment: so I shld remove`fastExit`? also I see u passed `errors.collect('number')` I believe that and `name` attru need to the same and not same as data property?

Comment: The example above is a trim down version of what I want to do. There is a slight problem that even after I comment out my `extend` for a field, it still shown which make me think if errors are a closure function?

Comment: the fieldName "number" should be attached as  attribute to the input... e.g. `<input name='number'>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213228/discussion-between-nofel-and-denis-tsoi).